# Making WPF ListBoxItems selectable

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox, selecteditem, listboxitem

I have a `ListBox` with a rather simple `ItemTemplate` defined - containing a `TextBlock` and a `Button`. This displays like expected, but there is a problem though. When I click the content of the `ListBoxItem`, i.e. the text or the button, the line doesn't get selected in the `ListBox`. If I click the blank parts of the line it does. I'd like the `ListBoxItem` to be selected when I click anywhere on the line. What's needed to achieve this?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeElements}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBoxItem Selected="ListBoxItem_Selected">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                    <Button>Click</Button>
                </StackPanel>                                                
            </ListBoxItem>                                            
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: [Here is the answer to your problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459786/selecting-a-listboxitem-when-its-inner-combobox-is-focused/1459885#1459885) The questionstarter was experiencing the complete same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Natrium Nope, the problem is different here,

1. You need to remove ListBoxItem inside DataTemplate. DataTemplate can not have item ListBoxItem, and it will not work correctly. Whatever you define in DataTemplate is automatically put inside ListBoxItem at runtime, so in your case, this is what it gets created.

> ```
> ListBoxItem
>     DataTemplate
>         ListBoxItem
>             StackPanel...
> ```

2. If you want to track selection event, then you should only catch ListBox.SelectionChange event, you dont need to track ListBoxItem_Selected.

Change your code to this.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeElements}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                    <Button>Click</Button>
                </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```