# Select a ListViewItem by clicking on the controls in its DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, datatemplate

I've written a custom DataTemplate for items in a ListView, something like this:

```xml
 <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomerStateTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            ...
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            ...
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="24" Height="20" ... />

        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomerStyle}" Grid.Column="0" 
                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       Name="nameField">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Name" />
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

        ...
```

and I've obtain my pretty style.
Now, if I want to select the item, I must click on the white space between the template controls. If I click on the textbox in the ListViewItem, it won't select like an item. So, is there a way to select a ListViewItem by clicking on the controls in its template?

Thanks thousand!

Comment: are you, trying to  use `textbox` as `lable`?

Comment: I could, but I want content to be directly updated. I've the same problem with combobox too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its possible to add a trigger on the ListViewItem which selects the item always then the keyboardfocus is inside of the item. As you do that on the ListViewItem you have the same behavior for all the controls inside the DataTemplate, which should be your solution...

example:

```xml
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="Data" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
      <sys:String>first</sys:String>
      <sys:String>second</sys:String>
      <sys:String>third</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
  <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="itemStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>


  <ListView ItemsSource="{StaticResource Data}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource itemStyle}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding .}">
        </TextBox>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

i hope its clear...

Comment: becareful, it changes the listview behavior: the selected item will be lost when the listview loses focus. the only solution for that i found so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/863167/4394435