# Selecting Item in ListView with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm-light, datatemplate

I have a ListView that binds and presents my ObservableCollection fine with the exception of selecting the correct item in the ListView if I select a TextBox in one of the DataTemplate chosen UserControls.  My DataTemplate selects a View based on the Type in the ObservableCollection, currently only of type TimeDelay:ModelBase or AddPoint:ModelBase.

If I select any area with the exception of a TextBox in the ListView of either ListTimeDelayView or ListAddPointView, the selection is fine.  But, when a TextBox is selected, the ListView selection does not move, see image.  The blue selection should move down to Move ddddd.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:TimeDelay}">
        <local:ListTimeDelayView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:AddPoint}">
        <local:ListAddPointView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserControlOneStatic.MotionSequenceCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
     SelectedIndex="{Binding MotionSequenceStatic.MotionListViewSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Image below

[image]

Comment: @Chris - You are correct.  It was  answered there and I used the following code: -<Style  TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

Comment: Good stuff, seemed like that might have been the same thing =D

Comment: I noticed that my bindings aren't updating:-(  At least automatically until I click away.  Which it wasn't doing beefore.  So, I will look at it more closely when I get a second and will update.  I went w/ the easy fix (short amount of code) vs the longer code & explanation on the other link.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF input events bubble up the element tree. You can handle `GotKeyboardFocus` on your `ListView` and get the original element and it's `DataContext`.

```
void myListView_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = e.NewFocus as FrameworkElement;
        myListView.SelectedItem = element.DataContext;
    }
```

That's the basic idea. It should be the default behavior of ItemsControls, IMO.

EDIT: Chris linked to simpler and correct solution using XAML styling and triggers.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I feel bad as the question was already answered here.  [Selecting a Textbox Item in a Listbox does not change the selected item of the listbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653524/selecting-a-textbox-item-in-a-listbox-does-not-change-the-selected-item-of-the-l).  As you said, basic idea is the same.