# XAML GridView entries copyable (TextBox as ItemTemplate) - IsSelected not working anymore

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview

I need my GridView entries to be focused and copied, so I made a cell template with a TextBox:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Kat." Width="40">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Text to copy -->
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Category, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Problem is now: The user can click into the TextBoxes and copy their content but the selected row can only be changed if the user clicks on the very small gaps between the columns. The selected row (IsSelected) won't change when you click inside the TextBox.

Has anyone encountered the same problem and found a solution so far?

( I bet there's some kind of "...is not the same visual tree"-xaml-default-problem, but this explanation alone wouldn't help me. ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to your ListView:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653524/selecting-a-textbox-item-in-a-listbox-does-not-change-the-selected-item-of-the-l) question for further information.