# Select the associated ListViewItem when selecting a control inside the ListView DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, mvvm, winui-3

I have a WinUI 3 ListView that displays a list of items. Every item has a ToggleSwitch and a Expander. When i click on the ToggleSwitch or the Expander the ListView selection does not change.

I found some solutions for WPF but they dont work in WinUI 3:

[Selecting a Textbox Item in a Listbox does not change the selected item of the listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653524/selecting-a-textbox-item-in-a-listbox-does-not-change-the-selected-item-of-the-l/863167#863167)

How can I do this for WinUI 3 so that the associated ListViewItem is selected when the ToggleSwitch or Expander is selected?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to change selection when you do something programmatically, you can do it this way.

**.xaml**

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <Button
        Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestCommand}"
        Content="Click" />
    <ListView
        x:Name="ListViewControl"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items}"
        SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ToggleSwitch Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled" />
                    <Expander Expanding="Expander_Expanding" IsExpanded="{x:Bind IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

**.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewModel.IsProgrammatical is false)
    {
        ListViewControl.SelectedItem = (sender as ToggleSwitch)?.DataContext;
    }
}

private void Expander_Expanding(Expander sender, ExpanderExpandingEventArgs args)
{
    if (ViewModel.IsProgrammatical is false)
    {
        ListViewControl.SelectedItem = sender.DataContext;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
public partial class Item : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string text = string.Empty;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isChecked;
}

public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public bool IsProgrammatical { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<Item> items = new()
    {
        { new Item() { Text = "A", IsChecked = false,} },
        { new Item() { Text = "B", IsChecked = false,} },
        { new Item() { Text = "C", IsChecked = false,} },
    };

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Test()
    {
        IsProgrammatical = true;
        Items[1].IsChecked = !Items[1].IsChecked;
        IsProgrammatical = false;
    }
}
```

**Workaround**

In this case, the source collection is untouchable and we can't use a flag if the property was changed programmatically or not, we need to use the `Tapped` event to make the item selected. But unfortunately, the `ToggleSwitch`'s `Tapped` event is not fired (at least in my environment). Might be a **WinUI** bug (issue posted [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7698)).

As a workaround, at least until this bug gets fixed, you can use the `ToggleButton`. I tested it out and the `Tapped` event is fired.

```xml
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
    <StackPanel>
        <ToggleButton Tapped="ToggleButton_Tapped" />
        <Expander Tapped="Expander_Tapped" IsExpanded="{x:Bind IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

```cs
private void ToggleButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewControl.SelectedItem = (sender as ToggleSwitch)?.DataContext;
}

private void Expander_Tapped(Expander sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewControl.SelectedItem = sender.DataContext;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work as intended. When i programmatically expand an Expander or programmatically change the state of a ToggleSwitch, the respective event is triggered and the ListViewItem is selected. But it should only be selected by the user.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using the CommunityTookit.Mvvm to implement this sample, but it's irrelevant.

Comment: This looks unnecessarily complicated to me. My ListView is bound to an external ObservableCollection and automatically updates the contents as needed. So I don't know how to set the flag IsProgrammatical, as you suggested, if the ListView is automatically updated by the bound collection.

Comment: Then you should go with @mm8's solution but unfortunately the ``ToggleSwitch``'s ``Tapped`` event is not fired (at least in my environment).

Comment: I found a walkaround and updated my answer.

Comment: The workaround seems to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `Tapped` event for the `Expander` and `ToggleSwitch` and programmatically set the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView`:

```
private void OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    lv.SelectedItem = element.DataContext;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView x:Name="lv">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
            <Expander Tapped="OnTapped" ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I tried this first but this works with the ``Expander`` but not with the ``ToggleSwitch``. The ``Tapped`` event won't be fired even with ``IsTapEnabled`` set to ``true``. Since ``RightTapped`` and ``DoubleTapped`` works, I guess this is a **WinUI** bug. I'll create an issue in the repo